# Update HTML attribute from appended HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery

User is adding a new search field (input field + select element). When user selects from select element I am trying to update the "name" value from the input element. Unfortunately the following code results in the following error at the console.log line

`TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById(selectID).options')`

here is the code:

```
function updateName2(index){

  var selectID = "SEL"+index;
  var inputID = "AS"+index;

  var e = document.getElementById(selectID);
  var valueSelect = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

  console.log(valueSelect); //error here

  document.getElementById(inputID).name = valueSelect;
};

var index = 2;

// ADD NEW SEARCH FIELD
$("#addNewSearchField").click(function() {
$("#Form").append(

  "<input id='AS"+index+"' type='text' name='' value=''>"+
  "<select id='SEL"+index+"' onChange='updateName2(index)'>"+
      "<?php
      foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
        if($key=="select"){
          echo "<option selected value='".$key."'>".$value."</option>";
        }else{
          echo "<option value='".$key."'>".$value."</option>";}
        };
      ?>"
   +"</select><br>"
);
index += 1;
})
```

Comment: Try to `console.log(e)` it should be `null` witch explains the rest.

Comment: @NikolaAndreev yes it gives `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'e.options')` so it does not find the object at all ?

Comment: someone posted and deleted an answer that suggested `updateName2(index)` should be `updateName2('+index+')` and I agree but I dont think that is the root of your issue.

Comment: @NappingRabbit I deleted my answer at first, since I thought I had misread the code. I've now read the code properly and have undeleted and slightly edited the answer.

Comment: so if you make that fix and comment out the lines: `var valueSelect...` and `document.getElement...` then console.log(e) what do you get?

Comment: ahh I see that now @Tulir  my next question will be asking OP to view source and show the rendered JS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the select block

```
"<select id='SEL"+index+"' onChange='updateName2(index)'>"+
```

You use the `index` variable in its `id`, but in the function in `onChange` you just use `index` as a string, which doesn't refer to the variable correctly. This means that you're running `document.getElementById("SEL" + undefined)`, which returns `null` (as such an element does not exist).

Try this instead:

```
"<select id='SEL"+index+"' onChange='updateName2(" + index + ")'>"+
```

Comment: Star ! worked like a charm. For some reason I thought about it and I was sure to leave it as string. lesson learned. Thank you !